# vSphere API: cannot access wsdl

Tags: vmware-vsphere, soap, wsdl

Trying to develop a web-based app connecting to an existing production vCenter setup. According to the administration screens, the vSphere Web API's url is https://servername/sdk

When I try to access the API's wsdl at

- https://servername/sdk/vim.wsdl?wsdl
- https://servername/sdk/vimService.wsdl?wsdl

(and all kinds of games with port number that shouldn't work and, in fact, don't)

I get 404. Always.

Any suggestions how to connect to the API?

Note that all existing machines and services are running just fine: Web Client connects and shows data, Power CLI gets all kinds of good stuff when using that to query the server, etc.

Comment: What version of VCenter are you running?

Comment: VMware vCenter 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Fiddler when PowerCLI was going, I saw that https://servername/sdk is in fact the location of the API.

I took the wsdl files provided in the vSphere SDK download and hosted them locally. Then I was able to generate a SOAP client based on them, and then I pointed the client's endpoint to the actual service.